# AngularJS works once then no longer renders

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

So I am trying to list out some data from an API call, which is JSON. I am new to Angular and JavaScript and I think the whole Async thing is messing with my logic. Sometimes when I refresh the page, it works perfectly, all the data I expect to be there is, but then the next time I refresh its gone. This seems to happen when I change something in the controller.

```
var app = angular.module("hasRead", ['hasRead.controllers', 'hasRead.directives', 'hasRead.services', 'hasRead.filters','ngRoute']);

app.config(["$routeProvider", function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when("/books/:shelf", {controller: "BooksCtrl", templateUrl: "partials/books_list.html"})
    .when("/recomend", {controller: "RecomendCtrl", templateUrl: "partials/recomend.html"})
    .otherwise({redirectTo: "/books/read"})
}]);
```

controller.js

```
var ctrls = angular.module('hasRead.controllers', []);

ctrls.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope) {
});

ctrls.controller('BooksCtrl', function ($scope, $book, $routeParams) {
  $scope.books;
  var shelf = $routeParams.list;
  $book.getBooks(shelf).then( function(data) {
    $scope.books = data.query.results.body.goodreadsresponse.reviews;
    console.log($scope.books);
    $scope.$apply;
  });
});

ctrls.controller('RecomendCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.test = "testing";
});
```

HTML

```
<div>
  <book ng-repeat="review in books.review" review-data="review"></book>
</div>
```

Its a fair bit of code so here is a plunkr:
https://plnkr.co/edit/l3A6QF?p=info

Comment: the plunker doesn't work. (angular not linked correctly), figure directive is missing and $scope.$apply() is a function, add the parenthesis and see if it works better.

Comment: it was just there so you could see the code not to run the app.

Comment: Yes, that's what I figured. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't have the parentheses in `$scope.$apply();` in the controller.